# Ionic ion-refresher not working on my app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to reload the page on refresh. Below code works for me in browser but on app, it crashes on refresh.

```
<ion-refresher
          pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
          on-refresh="doRefresh()">
  </ion-refresher>
```

On my controller,

```
$scope.doRefresh = function() {
        $window.location.reload(true);
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};
```

Comment: what do you need the call window.location.reload(true) for?

Comment: to refresh the page, so that the last added value on db would be shown.

Comment: this is wrong way, you have to refresh scope data to reflect changes to your page.

Comment: since it's because of state, it uses the previously catched values.

Comment: for example if you have html page: <h2>{{name}}</h2>, to refresh one you have to write $scope.name="refreshed name" in the refresh function

Comment: I have tried this `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});` also but it failed to work.. This alone `$window.location.reload(true);` works on the browser not on the app.

Comment: in refresh method there is no need to go or reload the page, you only need to refresh data binded to html page. data is state of @scope

Comment: @AnatolyS ya, make it to work by calling the method which fills the corresponding scope variable. Let me check in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the refresh method there is no need to go or reload the page, you only need to refresh @scope's data binded to html page.